# Triggering a deployment in OpenShift with an external image

Tags: openshift

I'm attempting to trigger a deployment when an image is updated in OpenShift. The image is hosted in a private external docker registry. I've created an `ImageStream` that maps to this external image. When I push a new image to the registry, I'd expect the `ImageStream` to pick up the change somehow and update itself. However, when the external image is updated, the change is not immediately propagated to the `ImageStream`. How can I keep the `ImageStream` in sync with the image in our external registry?

I'm aware that I can tag the image with the [`--scheduled=true`](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/dev_guide/managing_images.html#adding-tag) flag to have the image periodically refreshed. The problem is that *periodically* isn't good enough. Is there a way to sync the changes *immediately*?

Answer (score 3):

One way to have it updated immediately and trigger a new build, is to run:

```
oc import-image imagestreamname
```

If the image on remote registry has changed, this will result in image stream tags being updated, which will then trigger re-builds of anything dependent on the tag, if the tag was updated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to tag the image to get it into the ImageStream immediately:

```
oc project os-project
oc tag --source=docker remote-images.io/image-name:latest os-project/os-imagestream/image-name:latest
```

In my current project we do the tagging via Jeninks-Pipeline after a new image is pushed to the remote registry.

To get it working, you have to configure this as well:

For every openshift project you have to link the secrets for pulling from the remote registry to a service-account (this commands work for pulling from another openshift registry):

```
export REMOTE_OPENSHIFT_REGISTRY_TOKEN='***'
oc project os-project
oc secrets new-dockercfg remote-images-io1 --docker-server=https://remote-images.io:443 --docker-username=unused --docker-password=$REMOTE_OPENSHIFT_REGISTRY_TOKEN --docker-email=unused
oc secrets new-dockercfg remote-images-io2 --docker-server=remote-images.io --
docker-username=unused --docker-email=unused --docker-password=$REMOTE_OPENSHIFT_REGISTRY_TOKEN
oc secrets link default remote-images-io1 --for=pull
oc secrets link default remote-images-io2 --for=pull
```